# Rails search form with no path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I would like my search form to work on all URLs instead of redirecting to the messages page. For example on the search for "hi":

```
on /messages return /messages?utf8=✓&search=hi&commit=Search

on /posts return /posts?utf8=✓&search=hi&commit=Search
```

In my application view (bootstrap styling):

```
<%= form_tag(messages_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
    <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Messages controller:

```
def index
    if params[:search]
        @messages = Message.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @messages = Message.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

Users controller:

```
def index
    if params[:search]
        @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

Message model:

```
def self.search(search)
    where("title LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

User model:

```
def self.search(search)
    where("username LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

If I copy and paste the parameters `(?utf8=✓&search=hi&commit=Search)` onto the pages, they work fine. I tried removing `messages_path` from the form, but I got an error.  How do I use a form path that changes based on which controller I'm using it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace `messages_path` with `url_for` that includes the controller/action hash:

```
<%= form_tag(url_for(controller: controller_name, action: "search"), :method => "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
```

This will give you the `/#{controller_name}/search` path based on whichever controller is serving the form view.

If you want the search to go to the index, simply use this variation:

```
<%= form_tag(url_for(controller: controller_name, action: "index"), :method => "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
```

and it will send the form to `/#{controller_name}`, instead.